# adding a msvc flag starting with "/D" results in it being treated as an added definition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

So I'm trying to add the `/DYNAMICBASE` option like this:

```
add_definitions(/DYNAMICBASE)
```

and the result in MSVC when I look in the project c++ command line options is this:

```
/D "YNAMICBASE"
```

How am I supposed to add this flag? I also tried using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` but the same thing happens.

Comment: [`/D`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8(v=vs.100).aspx) is a __compiler__ (_cl.exe_) flag, while [`/DYNAMICBASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384887(v=vs.100).aspx) is a __linker__ (_link.exe_) one.

Comment: Have you tried to add it via `target_link_libraries()` or by `LINK_FLAGS` target property?

Comment: @CristiFati add an answer and u get the points - I used ```CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS``` and ```CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS``` and it worked! @Florian thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment (*VStudio* specific):

> [[MS.Learn]: /D (Preprocessor Definitions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions) is a **compiler** (*cl.exe*) flag, while [[MS.Learn]: /DYNAMICBASE (Use address space layout randomization)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dynamicbase-use-address-space-layout-randomization) is a **linker** (*link.exe*) one.

is only half of the answer, and that is **finding the root cause**.

Translating it into something that *CMake* understands (setting the [[CMake]: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS.html) and [[CMake]: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html) variables) which is **solving the problem**, is @onqtam's merit.